# Lazy Load Content in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a website which contains lots of Content. If I consider only text in the webpage the size of the webpage is around 1.2 MB. I know how do lazy load an image but I want to load content as the user scrolls down. I am using HTML5 and some java scripts in my website, but I am just a beginner in java scripts.

Comment: Sounds like you will need to use AJAX to load the content; use same trigger as you do with images but instead of triggering an image to view, load content via AJAX. As a side note, this will affect your SEO if that's a concern.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the code yourself, I just make an example here:

[1]. trigger when the window scrolled to the bottom:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // when the scroll reaches the bottom
    if($('body').scrollTop()+$(window).height() >= $('body').height() - 20) {
        // load more content
        loadMore();
    }
});
```

[2]. use ajax to get the content patially:

```
// remember where to continue, 0 at the beginning.
var part_loaded = 0;

function loadMore() {
    $.get('get_more_info.html?part='+part_loaded++, function(data) {
        // do the content append action here. 
    });
}
```